# How to increment the key value by onclick if already the key value present in the array using TypeScript?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, typescript1.8

Here I am having the onclick function which is get the `Product_id`, `Product_name` and `Price` from detailss array. I am storing this value using local storage array wishlist.

Now I am stuck to update the quantity in local storage array wishlist,
I need to add the quantity if the productid already present in local storage.

```
addToCart(Product_id){
    
    var name=[{
        Product_id:this.detailss[0].Product_id,
        Product_name:this.detailss[0].Product_name,
        Price:this.detailss[0].Price,
        Quantity:"",
        
    }];

var a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('wishlist')) || [];
a.push(name);
localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(a));
console.log(Product_id);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function that only adds amount if item exists.

In this example amount is added by clicking on + button inside the cart:

```
addAmount(Product_id){
    let myArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('wishlist'));
        for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
           if(Product_id == myArray[i].Product_id){
               myArray[i].Quantity = parseInt(myArray[i].Quantity) + 1;
               localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(myArray));
           }
    }
 }
```

If you want to pass a number:

```
 addAmount(Product_id, Quantity){
        let myArray= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('wishlist'));
            for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
               if(Product_id == myArray[i].Product_id){
                   myArray[i].Quantity = Quantity;
                   localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(myArray));
               }
        }
     }
```

---

P.S. It's better to use **[Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage)** instead of `localStorage` for that kind of data.

> When running in a native app context, Storage will prioritize using
> SQLite, as it's one of the most stable and widely used file-based
> databases, and avoids some of the pitfalls of things like localstorage
> and IndexedDB, such as the OS deciding to clear out such data in low
> disk-space situations.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
...
constructor(public _storage: Storage){}
...
this._storage.get('wishlist').then((res) => {
     for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
         if(Product_id == res[i].Product_id){
            res[i].Quantity = parseInt(res[i].Quantity) + 1;
            //res[i].Quantity = Quantity;
            this._storage.set('wishlist', res).then(()=>
                console.log(res)
            );
         }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the value from localStorage and parse them into an Object

> `var myList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('wishlist')) || [];`

2. Find the product with the Product_id

addQuantity(Product_id,passedQuantity)
{

```
  let productIndex=myList.findIndex(eachProduct=> eachProduct.Product_id==Product_id);
  if(productIndex==-1)
  {
  //Product does not exist in the array
  }
  else
  {
  myList[productIndex].Quantity=passedQuantity;
  }
}
```

3. Stringify the array again and save it back in localStorage

> `localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(myList));`

Comment: I tried this code but this is not increase my quantity ...

Answer (score 0):

That's not what `localStorage` is for... Try `webStorage` instead.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp